# using margin auto and inline block inside while loop

Tags: html, css

I'm using while loop to display few group of people show in  different table.

I found that if I use `inline-block`, then `margin auto` cannot function.

I want this two table display inline and canter to the brownser
Bellow is my code:

```
<table style="display: inline-block; margin: auto;" class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
<thead>
     <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
        manager group 2
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Manager Name</th>
        <th>User Details</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Kelvin</td>
        <td><a href="admin_edit.php?id=<?php echo $mrow["id"]; ?>" >User Details</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table style="display: inline-block; margin: auto;" class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
        manager group 1
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Manager Name</th>
        <th>User Details</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>James</td>
        <td><a href="admin_edit.php?id=<?php echo $mrow["id"]; ?>" >User Details</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please update your question to show the HTML and CSS **output**, rather than the PHP and MySQLi input :)

Comment: you really shouldn't be setting a table to be inline-block anyway.  what is your end goal here beyond your margin issue, as that may provide a better solution to your problem than what you're currently asking?

Comment: @ObsidianAge sorry for my mistake, the question have been edited to html and css.

Comment: @scottohara May I know is it got another way to do inline on table? If don't using inline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin: auto;` doesn't do anything for elements set to `display: inline-block;`, you would need to set an actual unit value to the margin in pixels, ems, rems, etc, and the element would need to be either display block (or in the case of tables, you wouldn't need to bother updating their display, as margin auto works with display: table in a similar way)

But, since you're trying to center two tables, side by side, you should wrap those tables in their own `<div>`s, each with a max width set to them, and then you can target those divs to layout your tables as needed.  I've included a basic demonstration (which will need to be viewed at full screen to see the tables side by side, as they stack on top of each other if there isn't enough horizontal space... something you will have to consider as well, if you're working on a responsive interface):

```css
.txt-center {
  text-align: center;
}

div > div{
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  max-width: 300px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 8px;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid;
  min-width: 300px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="txt-center">
  <div class="example">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          example
        </td>
        <td>
          example
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="example">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          example
        </td>
        <td>
          example
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no problem.  Just another note, if you need to left align any of the content of your tables, make sure to set a ```table { text-align: left; }``` to reset the text. :)

Answer (score 1):

`margin: auto` does not work because as your table's `display` is `inline-block`, they flow on page like `inline` elements (like `<span>`). As there is no extra horizontal space available for an inline element (characters only know themselves, nothing more), `margin: auto` means "there is no margin" for `inline` or `inline-block` elements.

In your case, as the table's `display` is `inline-block`, you can center them by using `text-align: center` on their parent container, an example is attached below (if `body` is the tables' parent):

```
body {
  text-align: center
}
```